# Show that $T^2/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ be the torus and define the equivalence relation on it by $$(e^{2\pi it},e^{2\pi is}) \sim (e^{2\pi iu},e^{2\pi iv})\iff 2(t-u)-3(s-v)\in\mathbb{Z}$$
(a) Show that the class of $(1,1)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

(b) Show that $T^2/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

For (a), the class is $[(1,1)]=\{(e^{2\pi it},e^{2\pi is}):2t-3s\in\mathbb{Z}, \;\;t,s\in[0,1)\}$, where I have assumed $t,s\in[0,1)$ since otherwise we get repeats. But if $S^1=\{e^{2\pi i r}:r\in[0,1)\}$, then one could define a function $f:S^1\rightarrow [(1,1)]$ by $f(e^{2\pi i r})=(e^{2\pi i r},e^{2\pi i\frac{2r}{3}})$, which is continuous and bijective, and we can define the inverse as the projection of the first coordinate, so its inverse is continuous, and hence it is a homeomorphism. Is this reasoning correct?

If it is correct, then we can define a homeomorphism in an almost analogous way?

Comment: The map $f$ is not well-defined; what happens if you substitute $r = 0$ on both sides, and then instead substitute $r = 1$?

Comment: But $r=1$ is not in the domain of $f$

Comment: $r=1$ gives you $f(e^{2\pi i})=f(1)$ and $1\in \mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: But how about if you let $\phi:[(1,1)]\to \mathbb{S}^1$ be given by $(e^{2\pi ik},e^{2\pi il})\mapsto e^{2\pi i(2k-3l)k}$?

Comment: @George Yes, of course, but substituting the values $r = 0, 1$ gives you the same input value, $e^{2 \pi i (0)} = 1 = e^{2 \pi i (1)}$, but the "rule" for f gives two different (output) values. Therefore, it does not define a function.

Comment: Also, for (b): Hopefully it's true that $(e^{2\pi it},e^{2\pi is})\sim (e^{2\pi i(t+r)},e^{2\pi i(s+(2/3)r)})$, for $r\in [0,1)$ and that this is the only identifications we make. So use $\omega: \mathbb{T}^2/\sim \to \mathbb{S}^1, (e^{2\pi it},e^{2\pi is})\mapsto e^{2\pi i(t-(3/2)s)}$ and just project back ? As far as I see, since $(t+r)-(3/2)(s+(2/3)r)=t-(3/2)s$ we are sending all elements of an equivalence class to the same element in $\mathbb{S}^1$. However, still a bit unsure =).

Comment: By the way, looking back at this again. @Travis , Isn't the OP's $f$, just $f:\mathbb{S}^1\to [(1,1)], f(z)=(z,z^{2/3})$? how is this not continuous?

Comment: By the way, forget about my function $\phi$ above, as I realized it is not even well defined, since for $x\in [(1,1)], e^{2\pi i(2k-3l)k}=e^{2\pi ik}$. You of course have to incorporate $l$ in there as well.

Comment: @Christopher.L It's not a matter of it being continuous (though, that's an issue too). For any $z \in \Bbb S^1$ there are many $r$ for which $z = e^{2\pi i r}$, and to write $f(e^{2 \pi i r}) = \cdots$ that the right-hand side should be independent of which of those choices of $r$ is used. But again, in the OP's example, different $r$'s give different outputs.

Comment: @Travis Yes, I got that as well, from your comment that $f$ was not well defined, however, with all due respect (and I'm trying to understand it more than debating, trust me), I did not agree with that either. As I understand it, the OP has, with his parametrization of $\mathbb{S}^1$, defined a function $F=f\circ f': [0,1)\to\mathbb{S}^1\to [(1,1)]$, where $f'$ is continuous and bijective and $f(z)=(z,z^{2/3})$. So, as the OP stated, there's no reason to plug in $r=1$ since it is never the case that $r=1$. So, my question is, what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: I think I understand what's going on here: If OP is defining $f(e^{2 \pi i r}) = \cdots$ *only* for $r \in [0, 1)$, then $f(e^{2 \pi i r})$ is badly misleading notation! (OP said that "r = 1" is not in the domain of $f$---which strictly doesn't make sense----so I understood there to be a conceptual issue on their part.)

Comment: (Also, as written the given rule for $f$ gives an output in $T^2$, not in $T^2 / S^1$.)

Comment: @Travis : Good, ok, well at least I got the implications of that notation. Well, the first question was to show $[(1,1)]\cong \mathbb{S}^1$, so the output of $f$ should be in $\mathbb{T}^2$, as we are mapping to all elements of a class and not to the classes them selves. But we should keep this conversation short, as MSE politely suggests. I just wanted to straighten out any ambiguities. Hopefully someone will put together an answer. I am still curious about my $\omega$ above, as an answer for (b).